# split quantity values 10 rows each row quantity value 1

Tags: oracle, xmltype, xmltable

```
<ROWSET>
 <ROW>
<PONumber>XYZ-3450462</PONumber>
<OfferName>XYZ COMPONENT</OfferName>
<INVLOC>XYZ-ABC2042</INVLOC>
<Quantity>10</Quantity>
</ROW>
```

each record quantity value 1, the total sum of quantity value from table should be same with in the xml quantity value

Output like below :

```
---------------------------- 
PONumber OfferName WarehouseLocation Quantity 
XYZ-3450462 XYZ COMPONENT XYZ-ABC2042 1 
XYZ-3450462 XYZ COMPONENT XYZ-ABC2042 1 
XYZ-3450462 XYZ COMPONENT XYZ-ABC2042 1 
XYZ-3450462 XYZ COMPONENT XYZ-ABC2042 1
```

Comment: Output like below :
----------------------------
PONumber      OfferName                   WarehouseLocation      Quantity

XYZ-3450462   XYZ COMPONENT         XYZ-ABC2042                  1
XYZ-3450462   XYZ COMPONENT         XYZ-ABC2042                  1
XYZ-3450462   XYZ COMPONENT         XYZ-ABC2042                  1
XYZ-3450462   XYZ COMPONENT         XYZ-ABC2042                  1

Comment: So the desired output should have 10 rows, not 4?

Comment: Also, are you able to extract the values from the xml string, and you just need help creating 10 rows out of one, or do you also need help extracting the data from the xml string?

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH table_name ( xml ) AS (
  SELECT '<ROWSET>
<ROW><PONumber>XYZ-3450462</PONumber><OfferName>XYZ COMPONENT</OfferName>
     <INVLOC>XYZ-ABC2042</INVLOC><Quantity>10</Quantity></ROW>
<ROW><PONumber>ABC-1234567</PONumber><OfferName>ABC COMPONENT</OfferName>
     <INVLOC>ABC-XYZ1234</INVLOC><Quantity>3</Quantity></ROW>
</ROWSET>' FROM DUAL
),
xml_data ( PONumber, OfferName, INVLOC, Quantity, RN ) AS (
  SELECT  PONumber, OfferName, INVLOC, 1, Quantity
  FROM    table_name t,
          XMLTable(
            '/ROWSET/ROW'
            PASSING XMLType( t.xml )
            COLUMNS PONumber  VARCHAR2(20) PATH '/ROW/PONumber',
                    OfferName VARCHAR2(20) PATH '/ROW/OfferName',
                    INVLOC    VARCHAR2(20) PATH '/ROW/INVLOC',
                    Quantity  NUMBER(5,0)  PATH '/ROW/Quantity'
         ) x
UNION ALL
  SELECT  PONumber, OfferName, INVLOC, 1, RN - 1
  FROM    xml_data
  WHERE   RN > 1
)
SELECT PONumber, OfferName, INVLOC, Quantity FROM xml_data;
```

Comment: thanks for sharing knowledge ....! suppose if the data of xml table row sets are not similar structure , so in that situation what we will do..?

Comment: how to extract data  from the above xml data using PLSQL,in that data file row set data column change dynamically and split quantity  each each record quantity value 1, the total sum of quantity value from table should be same with in the xml quantity value

Comment: Please clarify your question rather than putting comments on my answer and suggesting edits to my answer that overwrite it.